# How to optimise MySQL query with INNER JOINs and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this query:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT mi.*, i1.sizes as tile_photo_sizes,
       i1.filename as tile_photo_filename,
       v.title_cached as venue_title,
       v.subtitle_cached as venue_subtitle,
       v.slug as venue_slug
FROM menuitems mi
INNER JOIN images i1 ON i1.id = mi.tile_photo_id
INNER JOIN menus m ON m.id = mi.menu_id
INNER JOIN venues v ON v.id = m.venue_id
WHERE NOT m.is_deleted AND v.slug="teplo" AND
      m.is_published AND v.is_published
ORDER BY mi.number ASC
```

I'm seing the following result:

[image]

I've tried to add separate indexes for each column used in `join`, `where` and `order by`, but it still uses temporary file.

I would not want to optimise it, but occasionally this results in error that can be fixed only by hosting provider:  `Can't create/write to file '/mysql-temp/#sql_64e0_0.MYD' (Errcode: 17)`

The largest table is menuitems (6,867), then goes images (944), menus (85), venues (79).

UPD: Removing ORDER BY doesn't use temporary file

[image]

Comment: Is the temporary file related to your ORDER BY? What happens to the EXPLAIN plan if you remove the ORDER BY?

Comment: Not sure at 100%, but could be worth trying to modify the index on "menu_id" to include also the "number" column and see if it can be used also for ORDER BY.

Comment: @davidethell, removing ORDER BY doesn't use temporary file.

Comment: @Emyl, I've tried to modify index, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your query to put the main JOIN logic in a subquery and see if the EXPLAIN performs any better:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT mi.*, i1.sizes as tile_photo_sizes,
       i1.filename as tile_photo_filename,
       v.title_cached as venue_title,
       v.subtitle_cached as venue_subtitle,
       v.slug as venue_slug
    FROM menuitems mi
    INNER JOIN images i1 ON i1.id = mi.tile_photo_id
    INNER JOIN menus m ON m.id = mi.menu_id
    INNER JOIN venues v ON v.id = m.venue_id
    WHERE NOT m.is_deleted AND v.slug="teplo" AND
        m.is_published AND v.is_published
) as t
ORDER BY t.number ASC
```

This could likely perform another Temporary situation, but I am curious as to the EXPLAIN results for you.

Comment: Looks like that will remove the temporary table. Filesort just means MySQL was unable to use an index to determine the ORDER which is still bad. So it should get around your server problem, but still isn't an optimum sort. See this discussion: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/